# Polynomial regression with Gradient Descent: Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

Just for the sake of practice, I've decided to write a code for polynomial regression with Gradient Descent

Code:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime as gradient


class polynomial_regression():


    def __init__(self,degrees):
        self.degree = degrees
        self.weights = np.random.randn(degrees+1)
        self.training_loss = []
        self.loss_type = None


    def predict(self, x: float):
        output = 0

        for i in range(len(self.weights)-1):
            output += (x**(i+1) * self.weights[i])

        return output + self.weights[-1]


    def fit(self,X: '1 dim array',y: '1 dim array',epochs,lr,loss,ridge=False,reg_rate=0.1):

        training_loss = []

        if loss == 'MSE':
            loss = MSE
            self.loss_type = 'MSE'
        elif loss == 'RMSE':
            loss = RMSE
            self.loss_type = 'RMSE'
        else:
            raise Exception('Undefined loss function')


        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.weights -= lr*gradient(self.weights,
                                        MSE,
                                        [np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)/100]*len(self.weights),
                                        X,
                                        y,
                                        ridge,
                                        reg_rate
                                       )
            training_loss.append(MSE(self.weights,X,y))

        self.training_loss = training_loss


def MSE(w,X,y,ridge=False,reg_rate=0.1):
    total = 0
    weights = w[:-1]
    bias = w[-1]

    for i in range(len(X)):
        total += (np.dot(weights,[X[i]**(p+1) for p in range(len(weights))]) + bias - y[i])**2

    if ridge == False:
        return (1/len(X)) * total
    else:
        return (1/len(X)) * total + reg_rate*((w**2).sum())


def RMSE(w,X,y,ridge=False, reg_rate = 0.1):
    total = 0
    weights = w[:-1]
    bias = w[-1]

    for i in range(len(X)):
        total += (np.dot(weights,[X[i]**(p+1) for p in range(len(weights))]) + bias - y[i])**2

    if ridge == False:
        return np.sqrt((1/len(X)) * total)

    else:
        return np.sqrt((1/len(X)) * total) + reg_rate*((w**2).sum())


def build_graph(X,y,model):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

    #Scatter plot of the dataset and the plot of the model's predictions
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.scatter(X,y)
    X.sort()
    plt.plot(X,model.predict(X),c='red')
    plt.title('Model',size=20)

    #Curve of the training loss
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(model.training_loss)),model.training_loss,label=f'{model.loss_type} loss')
    plt.legend(prop={'size': 20})
    plt.title('Training loss',size=20)
```

Several tests

```
    rng = np.random.RandomState( 1) 
    x = (np.linspace(1,5,100))
    y = 3*x + 10 + rng.rand(100)

    x = x/10
    y = y/10

    degree = 1
    epochs = 120
    learning_rate = 0.9


    model = polynomial_regression(degree)
    model.fit(x,
              y,
              epochs,
              learning_rate,
              loss='MSE',
              ridge=False,)
    build_graph(x,y,model)
```

Output

[image]

And now with more complex dataset

```
rng = np.random.RandomState( 1) 
x = (np.linspace(1,5,100))
y = (10*np.cos(x) + rng.rand(100))

x = x/10
y = y/10

degree = 3
epochs = 8*10**3
learning_rate = 0.9


model = polynomial_regression(degree)
model.fit(x,
          y,
          epochs,
          learning_rate,
          loss='MSE',
          ridge=False,)
build_graph(x,y,model)
```

Output

[image]

Notes:

1. You might wonder why I moved functions for MSE and RMSE out of the class. The main reason is because `approx_fprime` (I renamed it as `gradient`, for clarity) requires loss function to place an array of variables for which we calculate the gradient as the first argument (see the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html)). If I am to move `MSE` and `RMSE` into the class, the first argument, of course, will be `self`.
2. Admittedly, Gradient Descent is [not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350130/why-is-gradient-descent-so-bad-at-optimizing-polynomial-regression) the best choice for optimizing polynomial functions. However, I would still prefer to use it here, just for the sake of solidifying my understanding of how GD works.
3. For more complex dataset (when we'd need to use higher degrees of polynomial), the model converges **very slowly** (see the training loss for the second dataset). If possible, I would like you to elaborate a bit on what might be the reason.

### **What can be improved?**

Any suggestions will be welcome: algorithm efficiency/code style/naming conventions, or anything else you can come up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Encoding polynomials

According to your code, you represent a polynomial 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^k$$ as `[a_1, ..., a_n, a_0]` which is odd to my eyes.

The most common way to represent a polynomial is probably`[a_n, ..., a_1, a_0]`. Then for example your `predict` function becomes

```
def predict(self, x: float):
    return np.vander([x], len(self.weights)).dot(self.weights)
```

which is vectorised (by using `.dot`), so it should be a bit faster.
On the other hand, we can vectorise it further by allowing vectorial inputs:

```
def predict(self, x):
    return np.vander(x, len(self.weights)).dot(self.weights)
```

This allows us to evaluate things like `predict(np.array([-1, 0, 1]))`.

One consequence is that in your error calculation code you can write something like

```
mean_sq_error = ((predict(X) - y)**2).mean()
```

which is vectorised and easy to read.

### Calculating the gradients

In (the euclidean norm) `norm_2` polynomial fitting reduces to finding `weights` such that the value of

```
norm_2(vander(x).dot(weights) - y)
```

is minimal. The minimum point doesn't change if we compose `norm_2` by some non-decreasing function from the left, so e.g. using any of

```
norm_2_sq = (^ 2)   . norm_2
mse_norm  = (* 1/n) . (^ 2) . norm_2
rmse_norm = (^ 1/2) . mse_norm
```

will result in the same minimum points. The most natural of these is arguably `norm_2_sq`.

Let us generalize using this norm. Given a matrix `A`, and a vector `b`, we'd like to find $$\operatorname{argmin}_x \| Ax - b \|_2^2,$$ 
but $$\| Ax - b \|_2^2 = (Ax -b)^T (Ax-b) = x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tb -b^TAx-b^Tb,$$
so its gradient is
$$
2x^T A^T A - 2b^TA.
$$
If you want, you can use this to calculate the gradients of `mse`, `rmse` using the chain rule. You don't need to use `approx_fprime`.

On the other hand, since its second derivative, `2A'A >= 0`, our functional is convex, so it takes its global minimum at the zero of its gradient, i.e. the solution of the so-called normal equation:
$$
x^T A^TA = b^TA \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad A^TA x = A^T b.
$$

As a practice problem, you can solve this equation using some iterative method (e.g. the conjugate gradient method).

### General comments

The general consensus is that function names should be written in `snake_case`, class names in `CamelCase`

There are a few unnecessary spaces `RandomState( 1)`, parentheses `x = (np.linspace(1,5,100))`. `class PolynomialRegression:` is sufficient (no `()` needed).

Given the ML context, I would reserve `weights`, `bias` for denoting the weights of a(n affine-) linear mapping.

Despite writing

```
    if loss == 'MSE':
        loss = MSE
        self.loss_type = 'MSE'
    elif loss == 'RMSE':
        loss = RMSE
        self.loss_type = 'RMSE'
```

you hard-coded `MSE` a few lines later.

Tangentially related: `globals()[loss]` would be the method named by the value of `loss`, assuming this method is defined globally.

Answer (score 1):

- `MSE` and `RMSE` are suspiciously similar. Shouldn't

  ```
  def RMSE(w,X,y,ridge=False, reg_rate = 0.1):
      return np.sqrt(MSE(w,X,y,ridge=False, reg_rate = 0.1))
  ```

  suffice?
- `MSE` could be streamlined:

  ```
      ....
      retval = (1/len(X)) * total
      if ridge:
          retval += reg_rate*((w**2).sum())
      return retval
  ```
- The loop

  ```
      for i in range(len(X)):
          total += (np.dot(weights,[X[i]**(p+1) for p in range(len(weights))]) + bias - y[i])**2
  ```

  raised some brows on the first reading. Indexing `y` with `i` - which enumerates `X` - is very suspicious. Is there any precondition on lengths of `X` and `y`?

  Looking at your tests it appears that \$y_i = f(X_i)\$, so they are of the same length indeed. I strongly recommend to make it explicit, maybe by passing a list of tuples `x, y` rather than two disconnected lists. I am not a numpy expert, so I can't say how it may affect performance.

  Similarly, I am not sure that `len(weights)` is a good choice for an inner comprehension. `degrees` seems much more natural.

  In any case, indexing here is anti-pythonic. Consider

  ```
      for arg, val in zip(X, y):
          total += (np.dot(weights,[arg**(p+1) for p in range(degrees + 1)]) + bias - val)**2
  ```
- I would like to see the tests exercising `ridge = True` case. If you don't expect to ever use this case, do not pass `ridge` argument to `fit` at all.